# self-encoded QR barcode?

Tags: image, recursion, infinite-loop, qr-code

I was wondering if it's possible to create a QR in some file format, say png, then encode the png in QR, such that the resulting QR is the same one you started with?

Comment: https://www.quaxio.com/qrquine/ a `*.js` file that QR-encodes itself

Comment: @darw: Perfection. Not exactly what I asked, but definitely what I was going for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *freespace* mentioned, it's not possible to encode an image in that same image itself, for several reasons.

I have created a QR Code which contains an URL which contains (again) the original image:

http://qr.ai/qqq

I really think that's the closest you can get.

Comment: Including the contents of the link would make this answer useful

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so. Each QR code needs to encode the original data along with variable amounts of redundancy.

So to encode the original QR code, you need the encode the same amount of information and additional redundancies, which means the result can't be the same since it encodes more information.

Answer (score 4):

There are different sizes of QR codes ranging from 21x21 to 177x177. They can hold anywhere from 152 to around 31,000 data bits. Unfortunately, even using 1 bit per "pixel", the amount of data a code can hold never reaches the number of bits required to store it.

There are sizes, though for which it is not far off. I imagine some simple compression algorithm, or maybe even ignoring common parts like the calibration areas could get to a point where you can store some representation of it in itself. It is feasible to me that you could find a way to store a qr code of some size as a qr code of the same size.

The problem then is constructing a code which creates itself. With different error correction options, there is room to fudge a few pixels around, which helps the probability that such a thing is possible, but it would still take a fair bit of magic. Perhaps some sort of genetic algorithm could do better than brute force, but you may need to read the full spec and build one cleverly by hand. The search space is pretty big.

Answer (score 1):

A QR code can contain max. 4296 characters. I assume this is unicode, and that two bytes are used to represent one character. This means that a QR code can contain a maximum of 7089 bytes, which is enough to store a small image (like a small qr code).

The only issue here, is that most QR readers expect qr-codes to contain text (not image data).

Comment: qrencode -o newQR.png \`cat originalQR.png\`
works on linux, but I haven't tried to decode it to see if it puts out uncorrupted png data. freespace's answer suggest it wouldn't...

Comment: Not unicode, QR code can store up to 2953 bytes. 4296 is alphanumeric only (less then 8 bits per char).